# How to setup wireless network downstream of wireless bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have been trying to extend my home network to a nearby building. My network is set up as follows:
[Please view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMlw2.png)

I have my main router that's hooked up to ISP. An ethernet cable connecting from that router to a KuWfi outdoor antenna (with PoE) (this product https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07Z4R827X/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). The receiver for that antenna in the other building (also PoE). I think the 2 kuwfi are currently set up as point-to-point, but have also have AP option. How do I now take that connection here at the receiving end and make another wireless network with router 2.

My question: how should I configure my second router at the receiver end of this network to have a wireless network, should it be bridge or repeater mode? I have some experience with this sort of thing, and I've attempted a few times but I think some issue with DHCP/static IP caused it to fail. All the terminology of accesspoints/bridges/repeaters is mixing me up.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in the other building is an access point device connected to the KuWfi by ethernet cable. Access point fuctionality can be achieved in several ways - e.g., buy something called an access point; or configure a spare router as an access point (lots of instructions online).

Regarding the KuWfi units: Configure the KuWfi unit connected to the main router as Master, and the KuWfi unit in the other building as Slave. Usually they come preconfigured like that. This causes the KuWfi units to provide the same function as if you had run an ethernet cable from your main router to the access point in the other buildng.

Conceptually, what is important to understand is that the two KuWfi units communicate with each other on their own wireless network, separare from your router's wifi network. Your main router and the access point in the other building don't know that the packets they are sending back and forth are being sent between buildings by the KuWfi devices.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the functionality of a second router (or at least your description doesn't call for a second router). If you configure the 2nd Router as Switch/AP only . Turn off any router functionality (DHCP, DNS etc.) and you should be all set (usually this is bridge mode).

Comment: it would be nice to include some info on how to improve the answer with the downvote, thx.